# Angular app crashes in IE , but not crashing when dev tools is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

Am facing one app crash issue in my ie11.
It is very difficult for me to narrow down what is causing the issue, because my app is having iframes and following technologies used.

AngularJs 1.5, Kendo UI and Jquery 2.2.3

Not able to find which part of the code is causing the issue. Beacuse of kendo or angular or jquery.

Below are my observation and tried few solutions after googling for 4 hours, still not able to narrow down.

1. Happening only in IE, Not in chrome
2. First suspected some problem in IE11 (refer screen shot). Then i registered 
   jscript9 dll. (regsvr32 jscript9.dll)
3. In Few articles mentioned could be because of browser add ons. Went and disabled all the add ons in the browser including silver light.
4. Restarted the machine
5. Tried in different versions of IE11 (11.0.9600.18283 & 11.0.9600.18638). Issue is happening in both the IE's.
6. Then i thought of debugging my code from dev tools. Then i opened dev tools no crash is happening everything works fine.
7. Then i noticed some console logs , thought could be because of logging.Disabled the logging in angular and commented all the logs throughout my application. Even after crash is happening. (But not happening when dev tools is open)
8. Enabled script debugging and tried , now application is not getting crashed.

Fully confused do not have any idea, how to narrow down.

Now i have to go back to my code and have comment few modules and i need to try. That will be time consuming for me, a gonna try no other way.

If anybody have faced this kind of issue before , please help me with some suggestions.

Thanks in advance
[image: Badri]

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem occurs because you have the Windows Update KB4021558 or KB4032782 installed.
You can remove it or install [KB4025252](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4025252/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-july-11-2017), which fixes the problem and supersedes the old KB.

Comment: Crash was happening in KB3203621, now i updated to KB4025252. It is not getting crashed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do i conclude which KB will crash and which will not crash.. Is there any way to find it out...  Because i struggled a lot for more than week to narrow down this one issue. But i could not succeed , this issue may happen again with future IE updates... So is there any clue or way to find these type of issue... Once again Thanks a lot..

Comment: Now we are facing the same issue again, in the KB4036586 browser version 11.0.46 . Windows got updated.